# Proxy forward different PORTs on the same HOST to avoid CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, proxy

I need to have Angular production app on my.domain.com, where production html and javascript is. 
I need to call api on same server as my.domain.com ip. 123.123.123.123:8080 on port 8080. App is on port 80. 
I want to call get JSON posts ( not jsonp ), and i face CORS problem. 
Is there any proxy that i can place on production, to have possible calls on my domain? it's normal api with gets and posts. I can't use grunt-connect-proxy since app is already in production. 
server is on apache.

Comment: If all of the code involved is your code, can't you set appropriate response headers to allow cross-domain requestions?

Comment: @nnnnnn this is not what the uses asking for.

Comment: If you're running an Express Webserver, you can use the `cors` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: API code is not exactly mine. This is an option, but i am looking for proxy solution, to not touch api app.

Comment: Any feedback cyan?

Comment: it turns out that i have direct admin on server and i need to set forwarding to server ip and port from domain.com/api . Setting on lower level with proxy module want work because direct admin would overwrite changes.

Comment: and directadmin offers only 301 redirect i see. That doesn't work with cors.

Comment: Yea, plesk, webmin directadmin .. all those tools are a bad due to its limitations.

Comment: You can achieve this with direct admin by using a custom template https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=2 in that way the solution I posted should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a reverse proxy to make it work =)... on apache (Linux) run the following commands in your CLI to install `mod_proxy`:

- `apt-get install sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html`
- `sudo a2enmod proxy`
- `sudo a2enmod proxy_html`
- `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`
- Restart you apache e.g. `service apache2 restart`

**Next)** Open your VHOST file and enter your reverse proxy configuration to forward a specific endpoint (in this chase a subdir) to your local API running on `Port 8080`). This file should be located near `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your-site-name.conf`. Don't forget to enable your VHOST configuration file.

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8080/
```

Restart you apache e.g. `service apache2 restart` again.

**Finally)** Configure your AngularJS application API endpoint to http://yourdomain/api/ and you are fine.